# While running the "pmrep massupdate" command, I see an error "workflow object workflow_name cannot be fetched. Any idea how to resolve it?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Command used:

{
pmrep massupdate -i modify_session  -t 'session_config_property' -n 'Stop on errors' -v 1 -u output.log_modify
}

Snippet from output.log_modify

**workflow object wf_DS_DW_SampleDim cannot be fetched.**

Massupdate Summary:
Number of reusable sessions that are successfully updated: 0.
Number of non-reusable sessions that are successfully updated: 0.
Number of session instances that are successfully updated: 0.
Number of reusable sessions that fail to be updated: 0.
Number of non-reusable sessions that fail to be updated: 1.
Number of session instances that fail to be updated: 0.

Not sure why it fails for certain workflows and works for others. Any idea?

Comment: Might be those workflows are checked out?

Comment: How would one know if the workflows are checked out

Comment: Open workflow manager and go to versioning --> find checkouts.

Comment: We dont use versioning in our informatica version. So i dont think that is the issue here..